# getch is beeing skipped in a while loop

Tags: while-loop, putchar

I have this function, while checks for correct input which need to be between 1-6 but when I call this function it just skips all the `getch` and all the `putchar`. What am I doing wrong?

```
    int firstNum = 0;
    int secondNum = 0;
    int thirdNum = 0;
    int fourthNum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int counterMiss = 0;
    int counterInPlace = 0;
    int condition = 1;
    while(firstNum<0||firstNum>6||secondNum<0||firstNum>6||secondNum<0||secondNum>6||thirdNum<0||thirdNum>6||fourthNum<0||fourthNum>6) //loop that checks for input correct
    {
        if(counter>0)
        {
            printf("enter ONLY numbers beween 1-6\n"); //if there were any incorrect input it will trigger
        } 
        firstNum=getch();
        putchar(firstNum);
        secondNum=getch();
        putchar(secondNum);
        thirdNum=getch();
        putchar(thirdNum);
        fourthNum=getch();
        putchar(fourthNum);
        firstNum-=48;
        secondNum-=48;
        thirdNum-=48;
        fourthNum-=48;
        counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a number of identical variables, use an array, not separate scalar variables. Separate variables like this look ugly and will not scale.

Also, you're initializing the variables to zero, and then testing if they are less than zero or greater than six. They aren't, so your loop doesn't run.